# Number of optically active isomers of [Co(NH3)2Cl2(NO)(OH)]?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, stereochemistry, isomers

My Attempt:

Since Compound is of the form M[a<sub>2</sub>b<sub>2</sub>cd]

I got three optically active isomers of the form M[(ab)(ab)(cd)] , M[(ab)(ac)(bd)] , M[(ab)(bc)(ad)]
and since NO is a bidentate ligand, total number of optically active isomers should be multiplied by 2 due to linkage isomerism.

Hence i was getting the answer as 2*3=6 but answer given was 4.

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: NO isn't bidentate ligand, is it? Neither ambidentate...

Comment: @Zenix then i am still getting only 3 isomers but according to answer it is 4. Also doesnt NO donate through both oxygen and nitrogen?

Comment: I would write that as (ON)...

Comment: @RajeshKoothrapalli NO might be able in general to donate through both N and O, but it's sterically incapable of donating from both N and O *to the same metal ion center*.

Answer (score 1):

Try drawing out [M(ab)(ab)(cd)]: you'll see that it's actually optically inactive!

[image]

So, there are 2 optically active isomers, which along with their respective enantiomers adds up to 4 (M[(ab)(ac)(bd)] , M[(ab)(bc)(ad)],  as you've mentioned).

Comment: if a and b are drawn on the vertical lines then there is no plane of symmetry so isnt it optically active?

Comment: The plane of symmetry should pass through every type of ligand that occurs an odd number of times, here that means is must be vertical passing through the c and d ligands.  It exists in this isomer but you drew it wrong.  Also to get a superposition you need to combine refkection with a twofold rotation, which is allowed for an achiral molecule.

Comment: @Oscar Lanzi Right, my bad. I'll change it.

Comment: You have two choices really. (1) use the plane of tge paper and add the twofold ritation. (2) use a plane perpendicular to tge paper and passing through c and d, bisecting the a-M-a and b-M-b angles; this does not need the additional rotation.

Comment: @Oscar Lanzi can you explain what you mean by two fold rotation? i was not able to superimpose the mirror image on the molecule.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are two of $\ce{NH3}$ and $\ce{Cl}$, therefore in **trans-form**, we can always draw a plane of symmetry (in figure) to which the **trans-line** (in figure) is normal as depicted below for $\ce{Cl}$,

[image]

So, only that configuration will be optically active which has both the groups in **cis-form** as follows,

[image]

which gives us **two** optical isomers (this and its mirror image). The other two optical isomers can be drawn by **swapping** the positions of $\ce{NO}$ and $\ce{OH}$ in the above figure.

Hence, we get a total of four.